# Artifact when DOF is applied to layered render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, render-layers, depth-of-field, artifacts

[image: Example image]

Notice that the background follows around the skin of the body and cuts through the hair, which is on a separate layer from the body

Comment: Can you post the blend?

Comment: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=BE95339348EC8314!33330&authkey=!AA7asqnYZplo8pA&ithint=file%2cblend1

Comment: can you pack the textures into the file and re-upload it? Otherwise we only get pink textures and is impossible to reproduce the issue you're having.

Comment: Files are now packed, should be up in a few minutes or so using the same link

Comment: I just tried going there with no success. Did you remove it?

Comment: It's the same copy that I work on, so maybe when it syncs (every time I save) it's unavailable. I'll make a shared copy and send that link.